# Are localhost redirect URIs with ephemeral ports possible in Windows Server 2022 AD FS

Tags: windows, oauth-2.0, adfs

I am trying to set up OAuth2 authentication with a localhost redirect URI. The local application has a webserver running on an ephemeral port which the ADFS should redirect the browser to once the user has been authenticated.

According to the Azure Active Directory documentation[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#localhost-exceptions), when setting a localhost URI as Redirect URI the port part should be ignored.

However, this does not work on my (on premise installation of) Windows 2022 AD FS. I keep getting errors like this:

> Error details: MSIS9224: Received invalid OAuth authorization request.
> The received 'redirect_uri' parameter is not a valid registered
> redirect URI for the client identifier:
> '62d2a1a5-dfc0-4793-975d-fcaea6da171e'. Received redirect_uri:
> 'http://localhost:38287/oauthlogin'.

If I change the configuration of the "Native application" to allow the redirect URI to match exactly (i.e. http://localhost:38287/oauthlogin) then everything works fine.

I tried "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" as well to no avail.

Is there any documentation available on AD FS 2022 concerning redirect URIs?

Is Windows Server 2022 in violation of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7.3 which clearly states:

> The authorization server MUST allow any port to be specified at the
> time of the request for loopback IP redirect URIs, to accommodate
> clients that obtain an available ephemeral port from the operating
> system at the time of the request.

Comment: I've just realised that I shouldn't have posted this question here but rather on serverfault or superuser. Maybe someone with sufficient privileges could move the question to the most appropriate site? Thanks.